# how to scrape data which has mathematical notations html generated and get it exactly into text format?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

i am trying to extract text from html using beautifulsoup. 
The html code is in below format. 
the code uses math tags to generate text.

"""

```
<p>

 <span class="aps-inline-formula">
  <math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <mrow>
    <msub>
     <mi mathvariant="normal">
      Pt
     </mi>
     <mrow>
      <mo>
       (
      </mo>
      <mn>
       1
      </mn>
      <mo>
       −
      </mo>
      <mi>
       x
      </mi>
      <mo>
       )
      </mo>
     </mrow>
    </msub>
    <msub>
     <mi mathvariant="normal">
      Ru
     </mi>
     <mi>
      x
     </mi>
    </msub>
   </mrow>
  </math>
 </span>
 alloys in the presence of adsorbing oxygen. 
</p>
```

"""
this html generates mathematical formula in browser(shown as below)

"
The method is applied to surface ordering and segregation at a (111) surface of 
Pt
(
1
−
x
)
Ru
x
 alloys in the presence of adsorbing oxygen "

i want to keep the formatting as it is get the data into text format using python. 
Please provide me some suggestions.

Comment: The style and the content are two different things. The website uses html to format the content of the formula. You can keep the html and use some tool that interprets it to keep the formatting (jupyter notebook for example). You can extract the content of the formula and use any other way to display it the way you want with the right tool (LaTeX for example). But you cannot have only the formula without any tags that express the way that the chosen tool will display it.

Comment: Hi Corentin, I haven't used jupyter notebook, but is it possible to get the formatted content from jupyter notebook to some database or file. you understood my problem correctly but i have to get these formulas which contain html generated superscripts, subscripts and all into some data base or file as it is viewed in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "The method is applied to surface ordering and segregation at a (111) surface of " in the html. But given what is here, you can store the html as a string.

Which will give output:

```
>>> print (text)
Out[36]: '\n\n\n\n\n\n      Pt\n     \n\n\n       (\n      \n\n       1\n      \n\n       −\n      \n\n       x\n      \n\n       )\n      \n\n\n\n\n      Ru\n     \n\n      x\n     \n\n\n\n\n alloys in the presence of adsorbing oxygen. \n'
```

Then use regex to remove the spaces and new lines:

```
import bs4
import re

html = '''<p>

 <span class="aps-inline-formula">
  <math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <mrow>
    <msub>
     <mi mathvariant="normal">
      Pt
     </mi>
     <mrow>
      <mo>
       (
      </mo>
      <mn>
       1
      </mn>
      <mo>
       −
      </mo>
      <mi>
       x
      </mi>
      <mo>
       )
      </mo>
     </mrow>
    </msub>
    <msub>
     <mi mathvariant="normal">
      Ru
     </mi>
     <mi>
      x
     </mi>
    </msub>
   </mrow>
  </math>
 </span>
 alloys in the presence of adsorbing oxygen. 
</p>'''


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')  

text = soup.find('p').text

string =  re.sub('[ \n]+', ' ', text).strip()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print (string)
Pt ( 1 − x ) Ru x alloys in the presence of adsorbing oxygen.
```

Comment: Hi, this is not the case, these math tags produces superscripts, subscripts and all. if i just keep the text, the meaning of the abstract is lost. my concern is to keep the formatted text (like formulas n all) exactly as they are viewed in browser.

Comment: Ok. So where are you looking to have the output? Into a table? Txt document? PDF?

Comment: output in csv file. i am open to save it in table as well but not in pdf.